# Copy active cell to other cells containing string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

In Google Sheets I'm trying to create a script that will take the value from the active cell and paste that value to any cell in Column B containing the string "HR".  Any ideas?

Comment: I've recorded a Macro but it really only gives me the the part where I select the file.   I'm so used to Excel-VBA so I'm having a hard time with this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too bad; you just have to wrap your head around a few concepts from Apps Script and Javascript to make it efficient. But first let's start with the naive approach!

```
function firstTry() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // whatever is open
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();   // this is a single-cell range
  var activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();        // could be a string, number, etc
  // Now let's look in column B for stuff to change
  for (var i = 1; i <= activeSheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var cell = activeSheet.getRange("B" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
    var valStr = String(val);                        // We could have gotten a number
    if (valStr.indexOf("HR") != -1) {
      cell.setValue(activeCellValue);
    }
  }
}
```

This will probably work, but isn't too efficient: each call to getValue() or setValue() takes some time. It'd be better to just get all the values at once, and then paste back a modified Column B when we're satisfied:

```
function improvement() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // whatever is open
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();   // this is a single-cell range
  var activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();        // could be a string, number, etc
  // Now let's look in column B for stuff to change
  var rowsWithData = activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var colBRange = activeSheet.getRange(1,             // start on row 1
                                       2,             // start on column 2
                                       rowsWithData,  // this many rows
                                       1);            // just one column
  // Let's get the data as an array of arrays. JS arrays are 0-based, btw
  var colBData = colBRange.getValues();               
  for (var i = 0; i < colBData.length; i++) {
    var val = colBData[i][0];                         // row i, first column
    var valStr = String(val);                         // We might have gotten a number
    if (valStr.indexOf("HR") != -1) {
      colBData[i][0] = activeCellValue;               // modify copied data
    }
  }
  // Lastly, write column B back out
  colBRange.setValues(colBData);
}
```

You could go further with a fancy filter function instead of looping over the data explicitly, but that starts to get less clear.

**Caveats** as the OP points out in comments below, blindly calling `setValues` like this will pave over any formulas you have. This would have been no big deal, except that this includes hyperlinks. You *could* get really involved by calling `getFormulas` in parallel with `getValues` and then decide whether to call `setValue` or `setFormula` depending on the original contents of each cell.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I tried both of these and get the same error.   "Typeerror: Cannot find function includes in Object .  Obviously its in the line where you are looking for "HR"   Any ideas?

Comment: Oh no, I forgot that `includes` is newer than the version of JS that Apps Script uses. An older string method `indexOf` should work. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks jjjjoe ....I'm now getting a different error.  TypeError"  Cannot read property "0" from undefined   in this line... var val = colBData[i][0];

Comment: Doh, because in a zero-based array you should do `i < colBData.length` and not `i <= ...`. Fixed

Comment: It worked perfectly!  Thank you very much and especially for the explanation tags

Comment: Glad to help! I know your account is new so you probably can't upvote, but would you mind accepting the answer now that it finally works? :-) That'll let folks browsing the tag know that the question is sorted.

Comment: Sure thing.  I did experience something odd.  In the same column as the HR's are in some of the cellls have a nunber, like 8889.  I have each number hyperlinked and for some reason it disconnected all of the links.

Comment: Oh ho, that adds a wrinkle! This is because hyperlinks are implemented as formulas, whereas I'm using setValues() on the whole range. This pastes a plain text 8889 over the formula `=HYPERLINK("http://example.com", 8889)`. For your situation maybe my naive approach is a better fit after all!

Comment: BTW: you should be able to just undo (Ctrl-Z) to get back to the sheet as it was before the links got pasted over. If that doesn't work, the revision history will bail you out.